# Issue with mysql/notification script

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, debian

First off, I want to say I dabble in programming, and am more of a networking/systems person.

That said, I'm trying to follow a guide to setup RPis as temperature/humidity sensors. The guide has worked well thus far, but I'm failing on trying to get it to send notifications.

The main python script is [here](https://pastebin.com/q9had0Eh). It basically pulls a list of variables from a mysql database, plots them, and then drops the plotted image into a folder for viewing via the web. That all works, but when I went into it to add notifications, it all comes crashing down.

I've isolated the *initial* issue with Line 124:

```
for row in cursor:
hightemp = hightemp + 1
```

If I uncomment this section, the whole thing just stops processing. From the *looks* of it, everything should work properly (and it was copied from a "working" guide post), but I could use some help in figuring it out.

Comment: I realized that for whatever reason, I didn't properly indent any of the additional code. Once I did this, things started working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `.fetchall()` method you can use here. Try instead:

```
results = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
for row in results:
    hightemp = hightemp + 1
```

Comment: The results = line works, but as soon as I comment out the for loop, it hangs again.

The loop still kills it, but I don't know why.

Comment: I realized that for whatever reason, I didn't properly indent any of the additional code. Once I did this, things started working properly.

Comment: Aha! Yes Python is rather particular about indentation :-)

Comment: Today's fun adventure is figuring out why the email code works differently inside an if statement as opposed to outside of it.

Comment: Before long you'll be a programmer who dabbles in networking/systems.

Comment: God I hope not. Honestly, I hate programming.